# How to get the map object?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have several maps in my web application. In some point of time I have to change the center of the map or the marker position. But I can't use the map object from the other .js file ("ReferenceError: map is not defined"). How to get the map object, if I know the DOM? I Know that the map uses id - "map_wrap".

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: you probably need to make your map objects global variables, if you need other files and functions to use them.  It'd help to add some sample code to your question that demonstrates what you're trying

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. I declare two variables (map and marker) before the map initialization function. In the function I override them. Now they have become global variables.